# Need Individual Arrays from ArrayList of ArrayLists

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Could someone show me how to get arrays from my ArrayList of ArrayLists? All the information regarding converting to an array using ".toArray()" seems to only apply to an ArrayList, not an ArrayList of ArrayLists.

To give a quick background: I am reading values from an excel table of variable dimensions (meaning it could be 1x1, 100x100 table, or anywhere in between) hence the need for ArrayLists. The number of columns and rows are calculated by the excel sheet for easy access in the java program itself (as shown below).

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    int columns;
    int rows;       
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("c:\\KalmanInputFile.xlsx"));
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    XSSFRow row1 = sheet.getRow(1);


    columns = (int) row1.getCell(7).getNumericCellValue();
    rows = (int) row1.getCell(6).getNumericCellValue();

    ArrayList <Double> innerlist = new ArrayList<Double>();

    ArrayList <ArrayList <Double>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList <Double>>();

    int i;
    int j;

    for (j = 1; j < (rows+1); j++)
    {
        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow((j-1));

        for (i = 1; i < (columns+1); i++)

        {
            innerlist.add((i-1), row.getCell(i).getNumericCellValue());

        }

        list.add((j-1), new ArrayList<>(innerlist));
        innerlist.clear();
    }
```

If I were to print "list" I would get the following:

```
[[1.0, 1.0, 9.0, 11.0], [0.0, 1.0, 10.0, 12.0], [2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]]
```

Each element in "list" is a row of the 3x4 table in the Excel file. I need all three of those elements turned into separate arrays for later use in a matrix algebra program that is already written.

Any help at all would be appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't it seem straightforward to convert each `ArrayList<Double>` into a `Double[]`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: `i < (columns+1)` could be `i <= columns` and thus clearer to read.

Comment: @LewBloch could you elaborate on the conversion you are talking about? Where in the process would I make the switch to `Double[]`?

Comment: Loop through the `List<List<Double>>`. For each `List<Double>` convert to a `Double[]`. What you do with each iteration's `Double[]` is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Double array1[] = new Double[list.get(0).size()];
array1 = list.get(0).toArray(array1);

Double array2[] = new Double[list.get(1).size()]; 
array2 = list.get(1).toArray(array2);

Double array3[] = new Double[list.get(2).size()];
array3 = list.get(2).toArray(array3);
```

Comment: I gave this a shot, @Sanjay but when I went to print the new arrays (array1, array2, array3) it printed out the memory allocation instead of the array itself:

`[Ljava.lang.Double;@2353b3e6`

any thoughts?

Comment: "Memory allocation"? `[Ljava.lang.Double;@2353b3e6` is not a "memory allocation", whatever you meant by that. It's the `toString` of the array, per the documentation for the array `toString` method. It has nothing to do with memory.

Comment: Hi @beguer, try printing all the elements of the array like this

  `for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
 System.out.println(array1[i]);
   }`

  Repeat the same for array2 and array3.

  Another way of printing is to use the Arrays.toString() method:
  `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));`